# Advantages of injecting by ObjectProvider in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Could you clarify what is the reason for the autowiring by `ObjectProvider`, if I can autowire the bean by class or interface?

```
public class MyBean {...}
   
public class MyService {
   @Autowire
   private ObjectProvider<MyBean> myBean;
}
```

vs

```
public class MyService {
   @Autowire
   private MyBean myBean;
}
```

Are the pros only in having the optionality check (`getIfAvailable`) and not-unique check (`getIfUnique`) methods?

Comment: It is lazy by default, you can get a list or stream and filter to make a selection on which ones you actually want. It is optional (check the getter methods) so you can check optional dependencies instead of doing a null check and auto wired with a `required=false`. All in all it allows for more flexibility (when needed). When needed is generally when doing auto-configuration or base configuration classes for a feature (like in Spring Boot or the different `@Enable*` annotations in Spring). So generally for library/infra code not application code.